# How can I send ios's network packets over two seperate channels, one over WIFI and one over cellular?

Tags: ios, sockets, vpn, networkextension

I am trying to build an ios VPN app. And I want to figure out a way on how to send UDP packets through my UDP tunnel over both the wifi and cellular interfaces ?? Currently ios doesn't allow us to forcefully send the network traffic through separate channels.

I want to know if there any way to combine multiple channels in ios??

And how does this company (https://speedify.com/) claims to have done this??

At first I was trying to use MPTCP thinking that it would work. Then I thought that I would create two separate sockets and duplicate the network packets and send those packets through it. But it also didn't work.

Now I am stuck. No idea how to proceed.